# combine two JSON stringified values into on JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm not quiet sure if my title is correct, but i currently have a duplicate-able form that get JSON stringified and another normal input that gets JSON stringified, so when clone is clicked the second input gets cloned and when submit is clicked i get the following values in console are:

```
{"dependant1":[{"name":"daniel"}],"dependant2":[{"name":"allen"}]}
{"mainmember":[{"name":"steve"}]}
```

How can i combine the two to get:

```
{"mainmember": [{"name": "steve"}],"dependant1": [{"name": "daniel"}],"dependant2": [{"name": "allen"}]}
```

Heres a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/uhJ7w/

and the code:

jQuery:

```
//Clone Tracking
var g_counter = 1;
var d_counter = 1;
var dependant = ["dependant"];
var input_groups = ["group-1"];
var group;
var name_input_groups = ["name-group-1"];
var values;
var name_fields=[0];
var name_input = "<input class='name' name='name' type='text' />";
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery(name_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(name_input).appendTo('#name-group-1');
    });
    jQuery('#clone').click(function() {
        clone_dependant();
    });

    function clone_dependant() {
        var oldId = g_counter;
        g_counter++;
        var id_newDiv = 'group-'+ g_counter;
        currentdep ='dependant-'+g_counter;
        var $clonedDiv = jQuery('#dependant-1').clone(false).attr('id', 'dependant-'+g_counter);
        var name_newDiv = 'name-group-'+ g_counter;
        $clonedDiv.find('#name-group-1').attr('id',"name-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
        $clonedDiv.insertAfter("#dependant-" + oldId);
        name_input_groups.push(name_newDiv);
        input_groups.push(id_newDiv);
    }

var result = {};
var dependants;
var mainmember;
var main_result = {};
var dep_counter = 0;
jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
    jQuery('.dependant').each(function(k, v){
        dep_counter++
        dependants = {};
        result['dependant'+dep_counter] = [dependants];
        dependants['name'] = $(v).find('.name').val();
    });
    jQuery('.main-member').each(function(k, v){
        mainmember  = {}
        mainmember['name'] = $(v).find('.main_name').val();
        main_result['mainmember'] = [mainmember];
    });
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(result);
    var mainData = JSON.stringify(main_result);

    console.log(jsonData);
    console.log(mainData);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {parameters: jsonData}
    });
});
//submit function
});
```

and then the html

```
<div id="main-member" class="main-member">
    <div id="label">full name:</div>                <input class="main_name" />
</div>
<div id="dependant-1" class="dependant">
    <div id="label">full name:</div>            <div id="name-group-1"></div>
</div>
<button id="clone">Add a Dependant</button>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

and also they have to be in there own each loop to work with the rest of the code.

thanks in advance :).

Comment: Look at knockout.js, you will like it :)  http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: the `$.extend` method works great, but why not just declare `mainmember` as a `key` of the `main_result` object in the first place? `result['mainmember'] = [mainmember];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building two separate objects just build one

```
    jQuery('.dependant').each(function(k, v){
        dep_counter++
        dependants = {};
        result['dependant'+dep_counter] = [dependants];
        dependants['name'] = $(v).find('.name').val();
    });
    jQuery('.main-member').each(function(k, v){
        mainmember  = {}
        mainmember['name'] = $(v).find('.main_name').val();
        result['mainmember'] = [mainmember];
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/uhJ7w/1/)

Comment: brilliant, so simple yet works amazingly :)... thank you so much

Comment: Hey i don't know if this is appropriate, but could you possibly take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374324/jquery-clone-able-inputs-foreach-overwrites-values/

Answer (score 4):

Just do not use two distinct variables `result` and `main_result`, but one only.

If you need them separately, copy all their properties onto a new empty object which you are stringifying then. You can use [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) for that:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify($.extend({}, result, main_result));
```

Answer (score 2):

[`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) can do it,

```
var theData = $.extend({}, result, main_result, true);

...
data: { parameters: JSON.stringify(theData) },
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify($.extend({}, result, main_result));
```

Documentation:

> **`jQuery.extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ] )`**
>
> **Returns**: Object
>
> **Description**: Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

---

Optimally, you should use a single object instead.

```
var data = {};
jQuery('.dependant').each(function(k, v){
    dep_counter++
    data['dependant' + dep_counter] = [{
      name: $(v).find('.name').val()
    }];
});
jQuery('.main-member').each(function(k, v){
    data['mainmember'] = [{
      name: $(v).find('.main_name').val()
    }];
});
...
jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    data: { parameters: data }
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for jQuery's extend

```
console.log(jsonData);
console.log(mainData);

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {parameters: jQuery.extend(mainData, jsonData)}
});
```