# Jquery clone-able inputs foreach overwrites values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm currently creating a clone-able id input field..

the only problem is on submit after validating the id it displays the same values for all duplicates in the console.

what I'm trying to achieve is simply to clone the field make it run through the validation and on submit return the values for each cloned field in JSON.

Any Help greatly appreciated.

Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/tBYSA/4/

and then the code:

jQuery -

```
//Clone Tracking
var g_counter = 1;
var d_counter = 1;
var dependant = ["dependant"];
var group;
//Clone Tracking
//General Variables
var input_groups = ["group-1"];
var idNumber;
var values;
//General Variables
//Generate variables
var id_fields = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13];
var id_input = "<input class='id' maxlength='1' name='id' type='text' />";

jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery(id_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(id_input).appendTo('#group-1');
    });
    //populate jquery generated fields
    //Cloning Function
    jQuery('#clone').click(function() {
        clone_dependant();
    });

    function clone_dependant() {
        // Store the value of the previous Id to insert the cloned div..
        var oldId = g_counter;
        g_counter++;
        currentdep ='dependant-'+g_counter;
        // Clone the Dependant Div and set a new id
        var $clonedDiv = jQuery('#dependant-1').clone(false).attr('id', 'dependant-'+g_counter);
        var id_newDiv = 'group-'+ g_counter;

        // Find div's inside the cloned object and set a new id's
        $clonedDiv.find('#group-1').attr('id',"group-" + g_counter );

        // You don't need to Loop thru the inputs to set the value
        $clonedDiv.find('input[type="text"]').val('');


        // Insert the cloned object 
        $clonedDiv.insertAfter("#dependant-" + oldId);
        input_groups.push(id_newDiv);
    }
    //Cloning Function
    //Validation
    function validate_Id(values) {
            idNumber = values;
            var correct = true;
            if (idNumber.length != 13 || !isNumber(idNumber)) {correct = false;}
            var tempDate = new Date(idNumber.substring(0, 2), idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1, idNumber.substring(4, 6));
            var today = new Date();
            var id_date = tempDate.getDate();
            var id_month = tempDate.getMonth();
            var id_year = tempDate.getFullYear();
            var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
            var age = Math.floor((today-tempDate) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var fullDate = id_date + "-" + (id_month + 1) + "-" + id_year;
            if (!((tempDate.getYear() == idNumber.substring(0, 2)) && (id_month == idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1) && (id_date == idNumber.substring(4, 6)))) {
correct = false;}
            var genderCode = idNumber.substring(6, 10);
            var gender = parseInt(genderCode) < 5000 ? "Female" : "Male";
            var citzenship = parseInt(idNumber.substring(10, 11)) == 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
            var tempTotal = 0;
            var checkSum = 0;
            var multiplier = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {tempTotal = parseInt(idNumber.charAt(i)) * multiplier;
            if (tempTotal > 9) {tempTotal = parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(0)) + parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(1));}
                checkSum = checkSum + tempTotal;
                multiplier = (multiplier % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;}
            if ((checkSum % 10) != 0) {correct = false;};
            if (correct) {
                 $.each(age_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = 'age-group-'+g_counter;
                    var agevalues = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val(age);
                    });
                });
               $.each(gender_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = 'gender-group-'+g_counter;
                    console.log(gender_input_groups);
                    var gendervalues = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val(gender);
                    });
                });
                return idNumber;
            }
            else {
                console.log(idNumber + "-wrong");
            }
            return false;
        }

    function isNumber(n) {return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);};
//Validation
//MainID
    $(document).on('keydown', 'input.id', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).prev().val('');
            $(this).prev().focus();
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', 'input.id', function() {
        if (this.value.match(/\d+/)) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.next('input.id').length) {
                $this.next().focus();
            } else {
                $.each(input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = input_groups[i];
                    values = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val();
                    }).join('');
                    validate_Id(values);
                });
            }
        }
    });
//MainID
$(document).on("click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    jQuery(this).siblings(":checked").removeAttr('checked');
});
//Multiple Inputs function

//Basic Validation
//Digits only
jQuery(".id").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }
});
//Basic Validation
//submit function
var result = {};
var dependants;
var dep_counter = 0;
jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
    jQuery('.dependant').each(function(k, v){
        dep_counter++
        dependants = {};
        result['dependant'+dep_counter] = [dependants];
        dependants['id'] = idNumber;
    });
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(jsonData);
});
//submit function
});
```

and then the HTML:

```
<div id="dependant-1" class="dependant">
    <div id="label">id-number:</div>            <div id="group-1"></div>
    <div id="error_id" class="error"></div>
</div>

<button id="clone">Add a Dependant</button>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Could you please put more details in terms of - What is an clonable input field - What you trying to achieve with it

Comment: You've got a lot of errors, in your fiddle try pressing the jshint button and fixing those. Also for every field I add I'm allowed to press letters. Finally every time I press the submit button the fields get cloned again.

Comment: the errors and such are most likely because its a part taken from my original JavaScript file.. ill see if i cant resolve them quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `validate_Id`, you're using a global variable `idNumber`, which will be assigned by argument `values`. So eventually this global variable will be the last validated number.

To solve that, you could change `idNumber` to an array indexed by corresponding `dep_counter`.

For example, 3 changes should be enough:

1. replace `var idNumber;` with `var idNumbers = [];`
2. change `validate_Id(values);` to:

   `var idNumber = validate_Id(values);`

   `if (idNumber) {
       idNumbers.push(idNumber);
   }`
3. change `dependants['id'] = idNumber;` to `dependants['id'] = idNumbers[dep_counter];`

BTW, you seem to like global variables, which should be avoided when possible. Even worse, you declared some local variables with the same name of the global ones.

Comment: for some reason im struggling with this, don't know if im doing it correctly, is it possible at all for you to post some form of an example..

Comment: i did, and when an incorrect id is inserted it returns false in console and when correct one is inserted it it returns no values... i need it to return incorrect and correct id's here's a valid id: 85 0929 5266086

Comment: As I mentioned, the root of bug is you tried to use one single global idNumber to store multiple validated numbers. Change it to array will surely solve this bug. I think you've got the idea.

Comment: almost fix, you'll see in my edits, a problem did pop up though when you duplicate it more then twice... in other words i duplicated it 5 times and typed in '1111' for the first duplicate and '222' for the second etc etc and the result i got was {"dependant1":[{"id":"1111111111111"}],"dependant2":[{"id":"2222222222222"}],"dependant3":[{"id":"1111111111111"}],"dependant4":[{"id":"2222222222222"}],"dependant5":[{"id":"3333333333333"}]}

Comment: The problem is that you changed the function `validate_Id`. This function should return false if validation fails, but now you always return the passed values.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sqauH/4/ <- does the same thing though without removing false..

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for you in fiddle..
code:

```
jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
jQuery('.dependant').each(function(k, v){
    dep_counter++
      dependants = {};
        result['dependant'+dep_counter] = '';
    $(v).find(':input').each(function(){
        result['dependant'+dep_counter] += $(this).val();
    });
    //dependants['id'] = idNumber;
});
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(result);
    alert(jsonData);
console.log(jsonData);
});
```

Comment: i looked at this, but in the original code there's more then just one input so it needs to be id specific..